# Replace command in Powershell V5?

Tags: powershell

Replace command is not working in PowerShell suddenly,

```
$Port = 1234
$Aport = $Port -replace '^1', '10'
$Aport = $Port -replace '^12', '100'
```

Expected Result
`10234`

But getting the output as **1234**.

Comment: Is there any error?

Comment: when i use two $Vars instead of one, each gets the expected result = `10234` & `10034`. this is with PS 5.1 on win7x64. what $Var are you using to see the result? it LOOKS like you are using `$Port` instead of `$Aport` ... [*grin*]

Comment: I am using $Aport, When i remove the 3rd line, i am getting my expected result.

Comment: @KLP - when i run your code, the `$Aport` variable has `10034` in it.

Comment: If you are expecting a result of `10234`, either don't use the third line, ot change that to be `$Aport = $Aport -replace '^12', '100'` as @Lee_Dailey suggested

Comment: Can't reproduce. For one thing, the code you posted would not produce any output at all, since all output is captured by variables. Also, the expected result would be that `$Aport` contains the string `10034`. Which it does.

Answer (score 0):

```
$Port = 1234
$Aport = $Port -replace '^1', '10'
$Aport = $APort -replace '^12', '100'
$Aport
```

Your 3rd line was using $Port and should be using $APort. Therefore, it wasn't really working, as it was using data from the 1st line which wasn't affected by 2nd line, as output from that was assigned to $Aport variable.

You can also simplify this:

```
$Port = 1234
$Port = $Port -replace '^1', '10' -replace '^12', '100'
$Port
```